# Using UnmonitoredAuto for very fast deploys

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We have an ultra simple stateless service and I am trying to get our dev/test deployments to be as fast as possible, recognizing I could risk deployment failure due to shortened timeouts.

That said, can anyone give me a comprehensive list of the deployment options that I can tweak to effectively shorten the deployment time? There are a bunch of settings and I just want to understand the ones that could make my deploys fast when using UnmonitoredAuto mode.

Can anyone save me a whole bunch of experimentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BrettRobi we are pretty much limited to what is in the parameters powershell Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade

-Force can help only in cases where there is a warning 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/start-servicefabricapplicationupgrade?view=azureservicefabricps

the 'best' option to speed up deployment would be to limit the number of nodes that the application is deployed to 
can set your _InstanceCount to = 1 as opposed to -1 as it is by default 
then it will upgrade just one Upgrade Domain eg UP0
and will just skip the others 
however this will make it inconsistent with your production deployment and will cause small outages during deployment so you can set this _InstanceCount or whatever is more appropriate

so far in all my testing was not able to make it any faster than this, hopefully they will add another option soon to deploy to all update domains at the same time

hope this helps